# Optimization - Compatibility for lodash merge with many args

Tags: javascript, lodash, es5-shim

Consider `values` as an undetermined list of objects.

I want an effective ES5 version of this:

```
var result = _.merge({}, ...values); // <-- This is what I want
```

Since `...anything` is not allowed I've made this:

```
var result _.reduce(response, function(result, value) {
  return _.merge(result, value);
}, {});
```

But I'm pretty sure it's not the best way to do ...

Any ideas ?

Comment: If `values` is an array then I think you can just use `_.merge({}, values)`. Alternatively your example can be simplified to `_.reduce(response, _.merge, {})`.

Comment: `_.merge({}, values)` will result to put values `in` instead of `with` the `{}` .

`_.reduce(response, _.merge, {})` is a good point ;) . But I think it is no more efficient.

Comment: One less function call for each value but that is a piddly amount of time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `Function#apply` on the array of values. You need to `Array#concat` an empty object if you don't want to mutate the original objects:

```
_.merge.apply(_, [{}].concat(arr));
```

Example:

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

var result = _.merge.apply(_, [{}].concat(arr));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```